# What exactly does "Publish language" option?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, localization, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce project - winform app - with two install locations by countries, one for the Czech Republic, one for Slovakia. 
Whenever I publish for different country I only change the Installation folder and the Publishing folder.

Recently I have localized the app to the Slovak language. But in the publish package I have "Publish language" set to Czech for both packages/publish locations.

[image]

According to documentation it should only affect the language of the ClickOnce installer. But in fact it affects the culture of the whole appliaction. I have even added this lines:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        //localization code

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("sk-SK");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("sk-SK");
```

But after install the app is displayed in the Czech language on Slovak Windows even with this code run at startup.
When I change the language to Slovak or Neutral, then it gives the following ClickOnce error on the client (because I have changed the Publish language):

> The deployment identity does not match the subscription.

When reinstalled with Slovak "Publish language" it is displayed correctly in Slovak.

Why do I not see the Slovak interface even if I set the culture manually within the code to `sk-SK` and the client has Slovak Windows and only the "Publish language" is set to Czech? Is there a workaround so that I do not have to reinstall all the clients?

Comment: I have reinstalled all the clients...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I'm late in responding, but just coming up against this issue myself. The reason you would still see Czech even though you had set CurrentUICulture to Slovak is because the "Publish language" setting in ClickOnce determines which language assemblies will be shipped to the client. Because ClickOnce was set to Czech, then it will only publish Czech .dll files to be delivered to the client. The only way to allow multiple languages (where language is determined by client Windows installation or via CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture) is by setting the ClickOnce publish language to "(Default)" or "neutral". See [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404266.aspx) for more information.

Unfortunately, it seems that trying to change the publish language after first publish is not possible, as this results in

> The deployment identity does not match the subscription.

as you discovered. This is the problem I'm currently trying to resolve without having to guide clients through uninstalling/reinstalling the program.